# If Multiple Cells = Yes Formula, ignoring blanks

Tags: excel, formula

I am sure this is pretty straightforward, but for some reason, I can't think of how to build this formula...

I have a database with over 8000 users, 1 user per line. I have 10 columns of data that represent different classes. Users that do not have any classes assigned have blanks in each class column. Users that completed their assigned classes have "Yes" in the class column (some users have 3 columns with Yes and the remaining are blank, some users have 9 columns with Yes). Users that did not complete their assigned classes have "No" in the class column.

I am trying to write a formula in a new column to show those that are 100% complete vs. those that are incomplete (only some of their classes have "Yes" in the columns and the remaining have "No"). I want the formula to ignore any blanks.

Suggestions on how to make this formula and not slow down the excel file with a bunch of nested ifs?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A1:J1,"No"),"Incomplete","Complete")
```

Where `A1:J1` is the range to be tested.

Comment: This works when every column in the range is "No". When there is a "Yes" in A1:C1 and a No in D1:E1 and the rest are blank, it returns a 0

Comment: Oh nevermind!! It works! It was just taking a while to calculate all the data